# Sentence-final 「ど～」?

Tags: particles

[image: http://image.lang-8.com/w200_h200/a6961de2d5466bc3955643b45d5bb56c51f33657.jpg]

I came across this image online.

What does the ど～ in はしったど～ mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While influence from television (from comedians on TV like [濱口 優](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%BF%B1%E5%8F%A3%E5%84%AA)) have popularized ど〜　into the general public and have made it to be used more jokingly. ど~ actually is a form of 方言 (seen in some 関西 dialects and other places), as seen in [播州弁](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%92%AD%E5%B7%9E%E5%BC%81) and 紀州弁 were ぞ and ど have become mixed.

Answer (score 6):

「～したど」 is a kidding way of saying 「～したぞ」.